# Gallery image width too small

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I downloaded a [website template](https://www.themezy.com/demos/77-free-photography-responsive-website-template) and tried to add a jquery plugin called [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

As described in the Getting Started section of the page, I added all required files and initialized the HTML:

```
<a href="images/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #2</a>
<a href="images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #3</a>
<a href="images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #4</a>
```

It works somehow, so the gallery appears when I click on a photo, but the width of the image in that gallery is too small:

[image]

I discovered, that when I remove the line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

from my template, it works as intended. But, of course, the template looks terrible then.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple name of exact class of lightbox in your own styles.

Comment: it's clearly a CSS conflict, you need to inspect your element and see the CSS that is applying from the file **style.css**